# PhpStorm keystroke for navigate between Version Control panel tabs (Local Changes, Log, Console, Shelf)

Tags: phpstorm

How to  navigate between Version Control panel tabs (Local Changes, Log, Console, Shelf) in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Show Local Changes
- Show VCS Log

Are two commands that you can assign a shortcut to jump to the relevant VCS  tool window tab. I am not sure if there is a command for the "Console" tab unfortunately.

But if you're in the tool window already (<kbd>Cmd+9</kbd>or<kbd>Alt+9</kbd>) you can use <kbd>Ctrl-Left/Right</kbd>(Mac), <kbd>Alt+Left/Right</kbd>(Windows) to cycle tabs.